# Django default value date and time when form opens up

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi guys I'm trying to pre-populate a date time field when my user opens the form. I need to display the `datetime` field too as the user may need to change it.

I've tried using `initial={'trans_date': 'insert date here'}` but can't manage to get it to work, and I would assume i would need to input a `datetime` variable into too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

trans.html

```
{% include 'head.html' %}
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
    <div class="container">
    Input Data



<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}


    <input type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-success col-sm-5" value="Submit">
</form>


</div>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):

    form = TransactionForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/transactions/')

    return render_to_response("trans/trans.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from bootstrap3_datetime.widgets import DateTimePicker
from .models import Transaction
import datetime

class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        exclude = ['ip']
        labels = {
            'amount':'Amount',
            'trans_date':'Date of Transaction'
        }
        widgets = { 
            'trans_date': DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", "pickSeconds": False},
                                         attrs={"placeholder": "Placeholder text"},),
        }  

        #fields = "__all__"
        #fields = ['for_you', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    trans_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    trans_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.trans_type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form init method

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['trans_date'].initial = #pre populated field.
```

This will render the form with the new date, when the form save it will be updated in the model.

Comment: Thanks @Othaman. i used your code together with import datetime